# Manifest requires output filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, precompile

I'm using Rails 3.0.10 and running rake assets precompile at production server and facing problem as manifest requires output filename.this code is already deployed on heroku server and working fine. Please provide a solution on this.

[image]

Comment: Check out the `manifest.yml` file in your assets directory paste itt

Comment: please refrain from posting screenshots of your desktop. instead, you can copy/paste the relevant information. that will make your question more readable and easier for search engines to index it.

Comment: Actually assets folder is not created maybe due to that error so manifest.yml is not there..please let us know further steps to resolve this error